# C# How to Read from Multiple Tables asynchronously?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asynchronous

I need to read values from 3 different tables, but this code will wait until it reads and finishes from the first table then start with the second read, and so on.

What is the best practice to await one time after all the 3 tables were read asynchronously?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProducts()
{
.
.
    var Products = await _context.Products.Where(x => x.Id == userId).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var appSettings = await _context.AppSettings.Where(x => x.rId == userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var openexchange = await _context.Openexchange.FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
.
.
}
```

Comment: await Task.WhenAll( ) may help

Comment: async and parallel is not the same.  And it's both not advised to do so. From the EF Docs: Entity Framework Core does not support multiple parallel operations being run on the same DbContext instance. This includes both parallel execution of async queries and any explicit concurrent use from multiple threads. Therefore, always await async calls immediately, or use separate DbContext instances for operations that execute in parallel.

Comment: I'm thinking you could create a list of Task and add the queries as to them (as a task) and then await Task.WhenAll(tasks)

Comment: Forget my previous advice, gsharp is probably right on concurrency issues. You may still look into the ef documentation on parallel queries or batching queries to see if there is a solution that would work for you.

Comment: I tried this, it did not work, so i guess EF does not really allow parallel data access:

Comment: var dbRead = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Products = _context.Products.Where(x => x.Id == userId).ToList();
                    appSettings = _context.AppSettings.Where(x => x.rId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
                    openexchange = _context.Openexchange.FirstOrDefault();
                });
                await Task.WhenAll(dbRead).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: @bobmason Don’t do this. Your old code was perfectly fine, but your new code in the comments is two bad practices – you went from perfectly fine to horrible code. Using Task.Run like here just wraps your I/O-bound operations in a CPU-bound task, thereby wasting one thread. It still reads one table at a time. Your initial code at least didn’t waste one thread and it used I/O-bound tasks. Also calling Task.WhenAll on a single task is pointless.

Comment: If you are doing a few big queries of a lot of data off a single server, you will most likely slow it down rather than speed it up by doing it concurrently.

Comment: @Charlieface how is that possible? I just wanted to utilize more of the unused CPU and disk access, parallel threads are always faster than a single thread, I can't think of a case that it's not. I really do not understand why EF read access can not be parallel, as there is nothing to track or records to change.

Comment: I very much doubt the server is CPU bound, it is nearly always IO bound (unless those queries result in really bad sorting or hashing, or you've somehow got a crazy fast SSD with a decade-old processor), therefore you are wasting your time with parallelization as it will just slow down disk access. Parallel threads are not the silver bullet, they are only useful when the single processor thread is the limiting factor. If you are doing video encoding, cryptography, Bitcoin mining and the like, yes. Reading data even off a fast SSD, waiting on a 10Gb or less network, no.